# a: hover issue with image issues

Tags: images, css

I am not sure what is wrong but the navigation a:hover has a image that when you hover over it shows. I am looking to see why there is a small space between the end of the image and slideshow. I am wanting to to butt right up to it where there is no gap.

See test board here

http://www.wpcreations.net/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a WordPress issue, although it *IS* an easy CSS fix.

The small space between the end of image and the slideshow is axtually 2 pixels wide and caused by the `#left-area` div.

You can just up the width by 2 pixels on #left-area. 
Like this:

```
#left-area {
  width: 639px;
}
```

It is currently 637px.

You could also up the padding-left by 2 pixels to acheive the same gap closure, although then the slideshow is a little off center.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's this

[image: this]

right here. Make that 100% or take it away and it works as you thought it should.

**edit:** I'm not sure I answered on the right thing afterall. But this will fix the one/two pixel gap between the left hand navigation against the picture on the right.

**edit2:** Yeah, it was what I thought, and the other fix does the same thing as well.